# Find minimum of date value from a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 table which has columns `Designationid` and `NewDesignationid`. I want to find the joining designation id based on the date. I don't know how.

My SQL Server table structure is like this:

```
 Designationid  NewDesignationID    UniqueID    EmployeeID  FromDate    ToDate  Comments    ApprovedDate    ModifiedBy  ModifiedDate    StatusID    ChangeTo    CreatedBy   CreatedDate
12  25  258 1700    7/19/2011   7/27/2011   Designation Change  7/28/2011   61  7/28/2011   8   Executive - HR - Associate Executive -  HR  61  7/28/2011
25  132 458 1700    7/28/2011   6/27/2012   Designation Change  6/28/2012   1700    6/28/2012   8   Associate Executive -  HR To RMG Executive  1700    6/28/2012
25  132 510 1700    7/13/2012   8/2/2012    Designation Change  8/3/2012    1700    8/3/2012    8   Associate Executive -  HR To RMG Executive  1700    8/3/2012
132 25  507 1700    6/28/2012   7/12/2012   Designation Change  7/13/2012   1896    7/13/2012   8   RMG Executive To Associate Executive -  HR  1896    7/13/2012
```

I also want to do it for every specific `EmployeeId`. Currently I have done so for a single `EmployeeId`.

Comment: I want to find the joining designation id based on the date.

This thing is not clear to me you want to join which both column and base on which date.show output.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just one row, you can use `top 1` and `order by ...`:

```
select top 1
    Designationid, NewDesignationID
from <Table>
order by FromDate asc
```

If you want this for every employee, you can use `row_number()` function:

```
;with cte as (
     select *, row_number() over(partition by EmployeeID order by FromDate asc) as rn
)
select
    EmployeeID, Designationid, NewDesignationID
from cte
where rn = 1
```

There're some subtleties in your question, and this one was discussed on SO many times. One of the quesions is - if you have 2 records with same FromDate and same EmployeeID, would you want to get both records, or just one (if you want one, then which one do you want?). If you want both rows, you can use method like this:

```
select
    T.EmployeeID, T.Designationid, T.NewDesignationID
from <Table> as T
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from <Table> as TT
        where TT.EmployeeID = T.EmployeeID and TT.FromDate < T.FromDate
    )
```

or

```
select
    T.EmployeeID, T.Designationid, T.NewDesignationID
from <Table> as T
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from <Table> as TT
        group by TT.EmployeeID
        having min(TT.FromDate) = T.FromDate
    )
```

If you want just one, you can use `row_number()` (see above) or `outer apply`:

```
select
    T.EmployeeID, TT.Designationid, TT.NewDesignationID
from (select distinct TT.EmployeeID from <Table> as TT) as T
    outer apply (
        select top 1
            TT.Designationid, TT.NewDesignationID
        from <Table> as TT
        where TT.EmployeeID = T.EmployeeID
        order by TT.FromDate asc
    ) as TT
```

Comment: i think CTE query is simple.so i have modified it and implemented it as WITH EmployeeDesignationChange as 
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY FromDate) AS StartLevel,* 
 FROM tbl_PM_EmployeeDesignation_Change WHERE FromDate IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT employeeid,designationid
FROM EmployeeDesignationChange 
WHERE StartLevel = 1;

Answer (score 0):

try this structure (your sample is unclear)

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
      min(FromDate)
FROM [EmployeeTable]
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Comment: i have already done this but i want to get designationid